# Will CFML (ColdFusion Markup Language) files still run after Adobe cancels Flash support?

Tags: flash, coldfusion, flash-cs5, cfml

I read that Adobe will soon stop supporting Flash and that most of the existing Flash applications will be shutdown. However, CFML isn't solely Flash-based. So, will it still run after Adobe cancels Flash?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ColdFusion does not require Flash to run at all -- it's a server side component.

Client-side components that ColdFusion has which utilize Flash may no longer be supported by browsers, but that doesn't have anything to do with the functioning of CFM.